# Print EditText output in \n format - android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I enter edittext text and I enter three lines of text. The output of these lines is as follows "Line1
line2
Line3 ". But I want it to be printed as" Line1 \ nLine \ 2Line \ 3 ".

```
 final EditText edittext = new EditText(getContext());
```

Comment: Not sure how you have entered the text but if you are sure you have space between words you can just do text.split(" ") and then format it the way you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output you want to achieve is this

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Use this code

```
String text = edittext.getText().toString();
List<String> splittedText = text.split(" ");
String formattedText = "";
for (int i = 0; i < splittedText.size(); i++) {
    formattedText += splittedText[i] + "\n";
}
Toast.makeText(this, formattedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```